# How this query generates two join operators in execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-execution-plan

Table structure with a clustered unique index on empno.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMP](
    [EMPNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ENAME] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [JOB] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [MGR] [int] NULL,
    [HIREDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [SAL] [int] NULL,
    [COMM] [int] NULL,
    [DEPTNO] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query

```
SELECT sal,sum(sal) over(PARTITION BY empno)
FROM emp
```

Query Plan

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plans with windowed aggregates normally use a common sub expression spool. A good write up of this type of plan is here [Partitioning and the Common Subexpression Spool](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/partitioning-and-the-common-subexpression-spool.aspx)

Suppose the table has the following rows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMP](
    [EMPNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SAL] [int] NULL) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EMP] 
VALUES (1,1),
       (1,2), 
       (1,3),
       (1,4), 
       (2,1),
       (2,2)
```

It has 6 rows in total with 2 distinct `EMPNO` values. The actual execution plan showing the actual number of rows emitted is below.

[image]

The segment iterator at the top of the plan adds a flag to the rows that pass through it indicating when it is the start of a new partition (i.e. the `empno` has changed).

The spool to its immediate left (primary spool) gets a row at a time from the segment iterator and inserts it into a work table in tempdb. Once it gets the flag saying that a new group has started it returns a row to the top input of the nested loops operator.

This causes the stream aggregate to be invoked over the rows in the work table (secondary spool in the plan), the `SUM([SAL])` is computed then this value is joined back with the rows in the work table (the third spool operator in the plan) before the work table is truncated ready for the new group.

The primary segment spool emits a dummy row in order to get the final group processed which is why the actual number of rows emitted is shown as 3 (number of groups plus one)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions with `OVER` clause can be rewritten thus: FROM table AS x INNER JOIN (SELECT partition columns , AggregateWithoutOverClause(...) ... FROM ...)  AS y ON x.PartitionColumns = y.PartitionColumns (if partition columns are mandatory - NOT NULL).

Example:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- OP's query
SELECT sal,sum(sal) over(PARTITION BY empno) 
FROM emp;

-- Reqwriten query
SELECT a.sal, b.SumSal
FROM emp a
INNER JOIN (SELECT EMPNO, SUM(sal) AS SumSal FROM emp GROUP BY EMPNO) b ON a.EMPNO = b.EMPNO;
```

Results:

```
sal         
----------- -----------
1           10
2           10
3           10
4           10
1           3
2           3

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'EMP'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

sal         SumSal
----------- -----------
1           10
2           10
3           10
4           10
1           3
2           3

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 21, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'EMP'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Execution plans:
[image]

This will explain only the *last join*:
[image]

The explanation for the *first join* can be found in section Per-group processing /  [Partitioning and the Common Subexpression Spool](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/partitioning-and-the-common-subexpression-spool.aspx).